# Trying to get property of non-object json in php

Tags: php, json

I am trying to get this code to work but I keep getting this error :

> Trying to get property of non-object..

I've validated my `json` object, but still no luck. I searched for the problem but didn't find any solution. First part of my code which creates the `JSON` and print it:

```
$response['team']['tid'] = $teamData['tid'];
$response['team']['name'] = $teamData['name'];
$response['team']['wins'] = $teamData['wins'];
$response['team']['group'] = $teamData['tgroup'];
$otherTeamNames = $db->query("SELECT name from teams where tgroup= '$teamData[4]'");

while($values = $otherTeamNames->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC) ){
    if($values['name'] != $teamData['name'])
    $response['team']['otherteam'][] = $values;

}
$response['success'] = 1;
echo json_encode($response);
```

the second part which will decode the JSON

```
$json = file_get_contents('http://localhost/pract/getSingleTeamById.php', false, $context);

$teamInformation = json_decode($json);
$success = $teamInformation->{"success"};
```

The output of `$json` before decoding:

```
{"team":{"tid":"2","name":"Italy","wins":"4","group":"D","otherteam":[{"name":"Uruguay"},{"name":"England"}]},"success":1}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Can you try like this ?

Instead of

> $teamInformation = json_decode($json);
>   $success = $teamInformation->{"success"};

Use

> $teamInformation = json_decode($json, true);
>   $success = $teamInformation["success"];

Comment: I did try this method, it give me the exact same error.

Comment: can you just echo $json and check comment rest 2 lines

Comment: [UPDATED] i used it again, it gave me nothing but the good news is the error is no longer exist...just empty output.

Comment: echo var_dump($json);

Comment: i got this :
string(205) " {"team":{"tid":"2","name":"Italy","wins":"4","group":"D","otherteam":[{"name":"Uruguay"},{"name":"England"}]},"success":1}"

Comment: ya that is correct , then it should work for second method

Comment: i used var_dump on the decoded JSON, it returned NULL

Comment: $teamInformation = json_decode($json,true);
var_dump($teamInformation); you should get array(2) { ["team"]=> array(5) { ["tid"]=> string(1) "2" ["name"]=> string(5) "Italy" ["wins"]=> string(1) "4" ["group"]=> string(1) "D" ["otherteam"]=> array(2) { [0]=> array(1) { ["name"]=> string(7) "Uruguay" } [1]=> array(1) { ["name"]=> string(7) "England" } } } ["success"]=> int(1) }

Comment: something wrong with while getting json check it. then everything will work